# Error while installing Wolfram-Engine

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, mathematica

I'm trying to install [wolfram-engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/). However I'm facing some error. After executing `sudo bash WolframEngine_13.1.0_LINUX.sh` I got following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                   Wolfram Engine 13.1 Installer
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Copyright (c) 1988-2022 Wolfram Research, Inc. All rights reserved.

WARNING: Wolfram Engine is protected by copyright law and international treaties. Unauthorized reproduction or distribution may result in severe civil and criminal penalties and will be prosecuted to the maximum
extent possible under law.

Enter the installation directory, or press ENTER to select /usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1:
>

The selected directory contains files and/or directories that may be overwritten during installation. If you have any files you wish to keep in this directory, you should exit the installer and move the files to a
separate directory before continuing.

Overwrite directory (y/n)?
> y

Now installing...

[**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************]

Type the directory path in which the Wolfram Engine script(s) will be created, or press ENTER to select /usr/local/bin:
>

  (1) Overwrite
  (2) Rename
  (3) Cancel

Type your selection, or press ENTER to select (1):
> 1


NOTE: Unable to determine the package manager used by the system--skipping the install of WolframScript system integration. Installer packages in the RPM and DEB formats have been left in
"/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1/SystemFiles/Installation". Consult your system documentation on how such packages might be installed.


Installation failed. See /usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1/InstallErrors.

A copy of the previous contents of the directory "/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1" can be found at "/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1/BackupDir-216407".
```

In the `.../InstallErrors`, There is nothing more than just warning about `egrep`.

```
$ cat /usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.1/InstallErrors
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
```

Comment: Can we assume that this question is about how to install the DEB or RPM package that is located in the directory indicated by the NOTE message at the end, on Arch Linux?  (Because there is actually no question in your text.)

Comment: It seems that you should have a Debian or RedHat based distro to be able to install it. Maybe the installation script (which is a shell script) will install some packages and dependencies in your system. You should check that script to detect what packages are needed and install the equivalents in Arch Linux. Btw, I saw Arch has its repository for WolframEngine. You can check [this link](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wolframengine) to install it (I actually don't have idea about how to install that kind of  **aur** packages)

Comment: Another solution if you were not able to install it is about using some container manager such as `docker`, `podman`. You can install an Ubuntu or Debian container and install WolframEngine with the given script.

Comment: I just tried to install it from arch repo, It resulted me to problem too: `==> ERROR: One or more files did not pass the validity check!`.  I'm not familiar with `docker` or `podman` but thanks I will give it try.

Comment: @Garid maybe there is a solution to that error or maybe not... Not sure if Wolfram is web-browser based or is a desktop application. If it were web-browser based you can run easily Wolfram (*via container IP*) from your current browser installed on your Arch. If it were a desktop app you should search about *running GUI apps in docker/podman*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thank for you comment, 
As far as I understand `wolfram-engine` is the non GUI application (but a CLI one, rather contain CLI one `wolframscript`), it's the core software that interprets wolfram-language (& other GUI front-end applications connects to it). I'm just trying to have a look at wolfram's language.

Comment: I hope if you install it on a container don't have so many problems. Because If it is a CLI app then it's even easier than the others. You only will have to familiarize with docker or podman (actually, there are more ways to create containers).